# How to verify error messages using Geb

Tags: selenium, groovy, geb

How do i capture the error messages generated on web page(for example an error message generated when a login button is pressed without inserting any username or password), how do i extract this error message "Username is required" using geb.
im using geb groovy based automation

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is currently not very clear. Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, what the issue is that you are facing and what you've tried so far to solve the issue. Also, consider posting relevant pieces of code and have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Comment: done. can you check it gain

Comment: No, you didn't. Where is your code (both HTML and Geb), your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You did not even mention how the error is displayed. Is it a DOM element in the page or maybe a JS alert? Everyone answering can only guess instead of analyse your situation, which is exactly what @Rushby did: He made an educated guess. Don't waste his time or anyone else's, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you would first model your page, and get the locator for the error you want to assert has been displayed.  Note that you want to set this to required: false as you would not expect it to be displayed when you first land on the page.

Page with example page error with ID of #pageError:

```
class MyPage extends Page
{
    static url = "/mypageurl"
    static at = {
        title == "My Page"
    }

    static content = {
        pageError (required: false) { $('#pageError') }
        submitButton { $('#mySubmitButton') }
    }

    def submitForm() {
      submitButton.click()
     }
}
```

Then you have your test:

```
def "If I try click Submit without filling out all form details show me an error message"()
{
    when: "I click Submit without completing all form fields"

        def myPage = to(MyPage)
        myPage.submitForm()

    then: "I am shown an error message on the same page"

        myPage.pageError.displayed
}
```

EDIT:

Noticed you mentioned getting the content of the error, you would call this instead to get the text:

```
myPage.pageError.text()
```

Comment: suppose i want to execute a query say - 
size { $("div[class='ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default']").size().toString()}
the above returns the size if executed on chrome developer console. How do i use this size query to return me the size from the webpage

Comment: This question appears to be unrelated to the one you have originally asked?  The code you mention should return the value as it does when you run it in the chrome console when you retrieve the "size" variable

Comment: im really sorry as its unrelated. how do i write the code to return me the size value to my groovy script.Thanks

Comment: Instead of posting unrelated follow-up questions you should provide feedback for the answer and maybe accept and upvote it if it solved your original problem. Ignoring the answer and asking more questions is just impolite, especially after you posted such an unclear question. Please learn to play by the rules here. Thank you so much.

Comment: im really sorry for this @kriegaex. im really new at this. thanks for pointing things out. Can you please help me about this "i need to return the size of a table based on the rows for which i have the following jquery  size { $("div[class='ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default']").size().toString()} how do i execute this jquery in geb groocy to return the size back to my script so that i can validate the size. Thanks

Comment: i appologize to the owner of the answer @Rushby too

Comment: No worries @MohammedAbbas - i would say post a new question.  Provide some html and as much info as you can though.